# Properties of set $\mathrm {orb} (x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, group-actions

Properties of set $\mathrm {orb} (x)$:

${\displaystyle \bigcup_{x\in X}\mathrm{orb}(x)=X}$;

$\mathrm{orb}(x)\cap\mathrm{orb}(y)=\emptyset$
  for all $x,y\in X, x\neq y$

How to prove it? Please help.

Appedix:
Let $\phi: G \times X \longrightarrow X$ - action of the group G on the non-empty set $X$. The set $\mathrm {orb} (x) = \{ \phi (g,x) \in X: g \in G  \}$ called orbit of $x \in X$

Comment: Be careful: it can perfectly well be, and in fact *it will be* in any non-trivial orbit (i.e., with only one element), that $\,orb(x)=orb(y)\,$ even if $\,x\neq y\,$ ,so that your last condition in the third line is wrong with general actions of groups on sets.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is false:

> $\text{orb}(x)\cap \text{orb}(y)=\emptyset$ for all $x,y\in X$ such that $x\not= y$

Instead, I think that you mean to say that $X$ is partitioned into disjoint orbits under the action of $G$.  This is given by the fact that the relation $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow y\in \text{orb}(x)$ is an equivalence relation.  [Here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit_is_Equivalence_Class) is a proof of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

And may not be as?:

Suppose that there is $a \in X$ such that $a \in \mathrm {orb} (x) \cap \mathrm {orb} (y)$
for all $x, y \in X$, where $x \neq y$. This means that $a \in \mathrm {orb} (x)$ and $a \in \mathrm {orb} (y)$ for all $x, y \in X$, that is $\mathrm {orb} (x)$  and $\mathrm {orb} (y)$ are two orbits having a common element. By definition, exists $g \in G$, such that $a = \phi (g, x)$. Hence, for some $g \in G$

$\mathrm {orb} (a) = \mathrm {orb} (\phi (g, x)) =  \{ \phi  (h, \phi (g, x) ) \in X : h \in G \} = \{ \phi (hg, x) \in X: h \in G \} = \mathrm {orb} (x)$.

Similarly, $\mathrm {orb} (a) = \mathrm {orb} (y)$. Thus, $\mathrm {orb} (x) = \mathrm {orb} (y)$. Hence, we obtain that if one element belongs to $\mathrm {orb} (x) \cap \mathrm {orb} (y)$, these orbits must be equal.

We obtain, that every two orbits are either disjoint or equal, so $X$ is the sum of disjoint orbits.